# How to Download Youtube Videos into different segments

Tags: youtube, firefox, download, firefox-extensions

I am aware of tons of Firefox Addons that enable downloading of Youtube videos. However, I am in a situation where my net connection frequently breaks and the download process is reset. I plan to download longer Videos in 10 minutes segments.

Is there anyway to do this?

Downloading whole video and then breaking into segments won't do, as a reset means whole download process will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use http://www.clipconverter.cc/.

Read the review here: http://www.mashgeek.com/download-youtube-segments/1768/

Comment: A bit of explanation, in case the links dissapear?

Comment: Well you enter the video link, select the conversion options, including start time and end time and hit download.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/home/index?s=lng_en) to download videos from youtube. Just make sure that clipboard monitoring is enabled, then copy the URL of the video from the address bar of the browser. Go to the Linkgrabber tab in jDownloader, give it some time to load and you're offered all available file formats and qualities.

It shouldn't be a problem when your connection breaks, because jDownloader will not reset your download, it just continues where it stopped.

Answer (score 0):

http://tubechop.com/

Lets you seeks to select segments within a web-app that loads the video from a youtube URI.

Comment: Just mentioning an application doesn't explain how to solve the problem.  Also, external links can become unavailable, in which case your answer would have little value.  Please see this link: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.